# Poisson Process - non-zero probability of more than one arrival

Tags: calculus, probability, taylor-expansion, poisson-distribution

Quoting Bertsekas' *Introduction to Probability*:

> An arrival process is called a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ if
>   it has the following properties:
>
> a) Time homogenity - the probability $P(k,\tau)$ of $k$ arrivals is
>   the same for all intervals of the same length $\tau$
>
> b) The number of arrivals during a particular interval is independent
>   of the history of arrivals outside this interval.
>
> c) Small interval probabilities - The probabilities $P(k,\tau)$
>   satisfy:
>
> $P(0,\tau)=1-\lambda\tau + o(\tau)$
>
> $P(1,\tau)=\lambda\tau + o_1(\tau)$
>
> $P(k,\tau)=o_k(\tau)$ for $k=2,3,...$
>
> Here, $o(\tau)$ and $o_k(\tau)$ are functions of $\tau$ that satisfy
>
> $\mathbb{lim}_{r\to0}\frac{o(\tau)}{\tau}=0$,
>   $\mathbb{lim}_{r\to0}\frac{o_k(\tau)}{\tau}=0$

Then we are given the formula:

$$P(k,\tau)=e^{-\lambda\tau}\frac{(\lambda\tau)^k}{k!}$$

> Note that a Taylor series expansion of $e^{-\lambda\tau}$ yields:
>
> $P(0,\tau)=e^{-\lambda\tau}=1-\lambda\tau+o(\tau)$
>
> $P(1,\tau)=\lambda\tau
>  e^{-\lambda\tau}=\lambda\tau-\lambda^2\tau^2+O(\tau^3)=\lambda\tau+o_1(\tau)$.

First of all, what are $o(\tau)$, $o_1(\tau)$ and $O(\tau)$ in the Taylor expansion? Does it have anything to do with Taylor expansion per se? I thought that $o$ is the little-o notation, but its [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) is quite different - $ f(n) = o(g(n))$ if $g(n)$ grows much faster than $f(n)$. In this case, it's quite different. Then what is it?

Secondly, the author doesn't prove that the $o$ terms above satisfy

> $\mathbb{lim}_{r\to0}\frac{o(\tau)}{\tau}=0$,
>   $\mathbb{lim}_{r\to0}\frac{o_k(\tau)}{\tau}=0$

as stated in the definition of Poisson process. How can we prove it?

**Most importantly** - why do we want it to satisfy the properties described in 'c) Small interval probabilities'? These 3 formulas are not arbitrary, there has to be a good reason for them.

Ideally, if we let $\lambda \to 0$ and it's natural to expect that the probability $P(k,\tau)$ to equal exactly $0$ in the limit, but apparently it's not possible (there will always be that tiny number, $o_k(\tau)$). Or does it equal $0$ in the limit?

Comment: Big O and little o notation are somewhat more general than you seem to have seen before. Specifically, $o(g(t))$ is a standin for a function $f(t)$ such that $\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$ goes to zero in some limit, and $O(g(t))$ is a standin for a function $f(t)$ such that $\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$ is bounded in some limit. The limit in question is usually either $+\infty$ or $0$ (though it could be anything). It is also usually not stated explicitly but rather left to context.

Comment: It looks like $o_k$ is the author's notation, but the $o_k$ are intended to be $o$ of their argument, as explained earlier. This is pretty sloppy, in my opinion, I think it would be clearer to not name the correction terms, and especially to not name them in a way which resembles an established notation.

Answer (score 2):

$o$ and $o_k$ are the authors functions with the **properties** that:
$$\lim_\limits{r\to0}\frac{o(\tau)}{\tau}=0$$

$$\lim_\limits{r\to0}\frac{o_k(\tau)}{\tau}=0$$

The actual definition of the functions is left undefined, and the author has said that they behave as above.

As these functions tends to zero, they allow for very minor variations to be treated as negligible. For the purpose of this section of the book, we do not need other properties.

The big-O notation used here:

$$P(1,\tau)=\lambda\tau e^{-\lambda\tau} =\lambda\tau-\lambda^2\tau^2+O(\tau^3) =\lambda\tau+o_1(\tau)$$

means that $|\lambda\tau e^{-\lambda\tau}-\lambda\tau+\lambda^2\tau^2|$ is smaller than $M|\tau^3|$ for some constant $M$ and as $\tau\to0$.

Then we can let:

$$o_1(\tau)=\lambda^2\tau^2+O(\tau^3)$$

because this satisfies the limit property the author has defined.

By the definition of probabilities we have:

$$\sum_k P(k,\tau)=1$$

and if $\lambda,\tau\to0$, when $k=0$ we have $0^0=1$.

The final point is that $o(\tau)$ becomes very trivial in relation to the  other calculations, and can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably answer a couple or all of your questions:

E.g. this one

"And actually, why do we want the oo terms to satisfy the two properties above? Why exactly these properties, not some others?"

Its one of several definitions of a poisson process and to be a poisson process it needs to satisfy those properties.

(You might need to zoom in to read it or read it here
[link](http://people.ufpr.br/%7Ebenitoag/cap5-Mcgraw-Hill.pdf))

[image: Two definitions of poissons processes and an explanation why one of them implies the other]

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, too short for the bounty.

Your question

> Most importantly - why do we want it to satisfy the properties
>   described in 'c) Small interval probabilities'? These 3 formulas are
>   not arbitrary, there has to be a good reason for them.

is indeed what makes the work needed to understand Poisson processes worthwhile. The three formulas that define the Poisson process are just what make it useful modeling many different phenomena.

There are a few applications on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Early_applications .

Here's a longer list, from http://www.aabri.com/SA12Manuscripts/SA12083.pdf

> Whether one observes patients arriving at an emergency room, cars driving up to a gas  station, decaying radioactive atoms,
>   bank customers  coming to their bank, or shoppers being  served at a
>   cash register, the streams of such even ts typically follow the
>   Poisson process. The  underlying assumption is that the events are
>   statis tically independent and the rate,  μ , of these  events (the
>   expected number of the events per time  unit) is constant. The list of
>   applications of  the Poisson distribution is very long. To name just 
>   a few more:
>
> • The number of soldiers of the Prussian army killed 
>   accidentally by horse kick per year  (von Bortkewitsch, 1898, p. 25).
>
> • The number of mutations on a given strand of DNA pe r time unit
>   (Wikipedia-Poisson,  2012).  • The number of bankruptcies that are
>   filed in a mont h (Jaggia, Kelly, 2012 p.158).   • The number of
>   arrivals at a car wash in one hour (A nderson et al., 2012, p. 236).
>
> • The number of network failures per day (Levine, 201 0, p. 197). \
>
> • The number of file server virus infection at a data  center during a
>   24-hour period . The  number of Airbus 330 aircraft engine shutdowns
>   per  100,000 flight hours. The number of  asthma patient arrivals in a
>   given hour at a walk-i n clinic  (Doane, Seward, 2010, p. 232).
>
> • The
>   number of hungry persons entering McDonald's restaurant. The number
>   of work- related accidents over a given production time, The  number
>   of birth, deaths, marriages,  divorces,  suicides, and homicides over
>   a given per iod of time (Weiers, 2008, p. 187).
>
> • The number of
>   customers who call to complain about  a service problem per month 
>   (Donnelly, Jr., 2012, p. 215) .
>
> • The number of visitors to a Web
>   site per minute (Sh arpie, De Veaux, Velleman, 2010, p.  654).
>
> • The
>   number of calls to consumer hot line in a 5-min ute period (Pelosi,
>   Sandifer, 2003, p.  D1).
>
> • The number of telephone calls per minute
>   in a small  business. The number of arrivals at a  turnpike tollbooth
>   par minute between 3  A.M.  and 4  A.M.  in January on the Kansas 
>   Turnpike (Black, 2012, p. 161)